# Resolving Whitelist Errors with Gmail and Docusign

Tags: plugins, gmail, whitelist

We added the Docusign Plugin to Google Drive to allow us to send a document signature request with the plugin.

If I add a second receipient, I get an error stating:

The requested URL

/addon-link-not-whitelisted

was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

The URL redirect is:  https://www.gmail.com/addon-link-not-whitelisted

I believe this has to do with whitelisting IP Addresses or emails from Docusign in Gmail.

Google says to add the IP Addresses of the domain range to the white List in Admin.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/60751?hl=en

The domain name range given in the docusign documents is here:

https://www.docusign.com/trust/security/esignature?_gl=1%2A4s9jbd%2A_ga%2ANTI3NTQzNDMuMTYzMjkwMDg0Mg..%2A_ga_1TZ7S9D6BQ%2AMTYzMzA3OTk1MS44LjEuMTYzMzA4MDAwNC4w&_ga=2.186986024.1006284391.1633017326-52754343.1632900842

However, Docusign does not provide the IP range in CIDR notation and I am not sure which domain range to choose.

So my question, What IP Range, written in CIDR Notation, do I put into the google admin whitelist to allow for this to work (assuming that this will resolve it).